# SVG code in DOM directly vs as css background source: effect on DOM traversal

Tags: html, css, dom, svg, dom-traversal

*Disclaimer: I searched but could find any factual answer to this question.*

I have to use a lot of svg images in my webapp. Should I directly dump the svg code in a DOM element multiple times, or should I use it as a css background property and apply the css class to these elements?

Background: I always wonder that increasing your dom length will have adverse affect on the DOM traversal but I do like the fact of using css to change the property of svg elements in the dom, instead of making new images.

Does anyone have any comparison of such sorts?

Comment: how exactly are you proposing to apply a CSS class to a CSS background property?

Comment: "CSS class to a CSS background property" is not what I meant. I was asking what is the effect on DOM traversal when we inline svg code vs using it as a css backgound-image property.

Comment: inline SVG is part of the DOM of the document, the contents of css background-images are not. Those background images have a DOM, you just can't access it.

Comment: The answer to your last point is try it and see. It may well depend on the browser, browser version, operating system, network speed and many other factors.

Answer (score 0):

If the SVG is being used as a `background-image`, then there is no way you can style it.

If you need to be able to dynamically style it with CSS, in your page, then you will need to inline it.

Comment: That is not my question. My question is what is the effect of inlining 100's of SVG elements in DOM directly vs using it as in a CSS background property?

Comment: Any increase in the number of objects in the DOM will obviously slow DOM traversal down to some extent.  But it will generally be negligible relative to what you are actually rendering.  The real answer as to whether it affects you, is to try it and see.  As a purely theoretical question, it is basically unanswerable.